# How to plot 3D surface with X, Y, Z when Z is a list of list

Tags: python, plot, 3d, geometry-surface

In my case, X is a range(0, 100), Y is a range(0, 10), Z is a list of list. Z has the same length as X, which is 100, and each element list inside of Z has the same dimension of Y.

`Z = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ..., [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]].`

I have the following code, but it does not work, it complains **two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 1.**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(200, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_ax)
ax.set_title("my title of chart")

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.set_zlim(0, 100)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)
plt.show()
```

I guess the error is due to the data structure of Z, how do I make a compatible structure with X, and Y? Thanks

Comment: So do you expect the first 10 elements of X to be plotted with the first element of Y and the first element of Z?

Comment: yes, X, Y, and Z should be plotted altogether. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic 3D surface plotting procedure. It seems that your `X` and `Y` are just 1D arrays. However, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` have to be 2D arrays of the same shape. `numpy.meshgrid` function is useful for creating 2D mesh from two 1D arrays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.array(np.linspace(-2,2,100))
y = np.array(np.linspace(-2,2,10))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = X * np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2);

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)

plt.show()
```